# Beautiful Soup fails to acquire prices from amazon at times

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, css-selectors, http-headers

In running a beautiful soup script, to acquire prices from amazon. I've stumbled across a problem where beautiful soup fails to acquire the prices at random often, in the form of empty lists in output.

```py
def getAmazonPrice(productUrl):
    elems = []
    while elems == None or elems == []:
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}  # to make the server think its a web browser and not a bot
        res = requests.get(productUrl, headers=headers)
        res.raise_for_status()

        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
        elems = soup.select('#mediaNoAccordion > div.a-row > div.a-column.a-span4.a-text-right.a-span-last > span.a-size-medium.a-color-price.header-price')
        print(elems)
    return elems[0].text.strip()


price = getAmazonPrice('https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-2nd-ebook/dp/B07VSXS4NK/ref=sr_1_1?crid=30NW5VCV06ZMP&dchild=1&keywords=automate+the+boring+stuff+with+python&qid=1586810720&sprefix=automate+the+bo%2Caps%2C288&sr=8-1')
print('The price is ' + price)
```

Output:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[<span class="a-size-medium a-color-price header-price">


                        $26.58



        </span>]
The price is $26.58
```

I feel like the issue stems from amazon blocking my scraping tool.
How would you use Beautiful Soup to scrape amazon?

Comment: you've already received a detailed answer regarding your question before. use `API` or Just use `selenium`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save the `res.text` to html file and you'll see that you're getting blocked by captcha.

Comment: but how did i get past the captcha sometimes, and it returns the prices>?

Comment: Great question, but you'll have to ask amazon, about when they block requests with captcha. Even real users sometimes get captcha: https://www.reddit.com/r/amazon/comments/606jut/amazon_captcha/